# CVS: Replace HEAD with a branch

Tags: cvs, branch

How do I replace the HEAD of a CVS repository with a branch?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check out this page, which has a pretty easy to follow walk through of branching and merging in CVS

http://kb.wisc.edu/middleware/page.php?id=4087

It also includes an example of replacing HEAD with a specified branch

### **Replacing One Branch With Another**

**Tag the end of your branch**

```
cvs tag merge_NEW_BRANCH
```

**Switch back to the branch you're replacing**

*To head:*

```
cvs up -A
```

*To branch:*

```
cvs up -r OLD_BRANCH
```

**Do the replace:**

*Replace head*

```
cvs up -jHEAD -j NEW_BRANCH
```

*Replace branch*

```
cvs up -jOLD_BRANCH -j NEW_BRANCH
```

Commit changes and tag if you need to.

Comment: I have a directory that doesn't exist in OLD_BRANCH but it does in NEW_BRANCH. When I run cvs up -jOLD_BRANCH -j NEW_BRANCH the directory is not created (and populated). Any idea why? Seems like this approach could miss other changes if it misses this directory.

Comment: It seems adding -d works but also adds directories that don't exist in the NEW_BRANCH. Sigh.

Comment: if you mean empty directories, it's normal CVS behaviour. You have to use additional option -P to not got them. So in the end: "cvs up -dP ..."